# Decomposition of vectorspace and subspaces invariant under a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Are the following claims true or false?

(1) Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ and let $V=W_1 \bigoplus W_2$ where $W_1$ and $W_2$ are $T$-invariant subspaces of $V$. If $T_{W_1}$ and $T_{W_2}$ are diagonalizable, then $T$ is diagonalizable.

(2) If $T \in L(V)$ and $V=V=W_1 \bigoplus W_2$ then $W_1$ is $T$-invariant.
($L(V)$ means all linear transformation from $V$ to $V$)

Um... I think (1) True (2) False..... need your help and comments!

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Comment: Can you also expand (i.e. edit) your question a bit and include why you think that (1) is true?

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer I think I don't have enough mathematical knowledge to use to fix my title. Thanks for your edition.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: I think you have made a mistake in writing out part (2); it doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @Rhys Actually, I solved (2). It is false. Consider $T$ as a rotation and take $V=R^2$, $W_1=span{(1,0)}, W_2=span{(0,1)}$.

Comment: Oh, so the only mistake was writing '$V = $' twice?  I thought there was supposed to be some other condition, as it is clearly false otherwise, as you've just found out! :-)

Comment: @noname Maybe you want to answer the question yourself, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).